# jquery autocomplete success only update selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using the following code below. It works great. When the user presses the @ sysmbol, the autocomplete fires off and completes.

I want to leave the @ symbols in the input, so they can have @user1: @user2: and so on. When the success goes, it is overriding the first @ choice.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){

// set array from cfquery above
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

function split(val) {
    return val.split(/@\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}

$("#tags")
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
/*
.bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
*/
.autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function(request, response) {

        var term = request.term,
            results = [];
        if (term.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
            term = extractLast(request.term);
            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");

                results = ($.grep(availableTags, function (item) {
                  return matcher.test(item);
                  }));   

        }
        response(results);

    },
    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {

        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push('@' + ui.item.value + ': ');
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join("");
        return false;
    }

    });
});

</script>
```